# My Javascript program won't execute anything but console.log() when it comes to picking up arrow keys

Tags: javascript, canvas, logic, rect

So this is my code:

```
   document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;

if (e.keyCode == '38') {
}
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        console.log("Down Arrow");
        g.rect( 200,200,20,20); << Here is the problem. This is ignored.
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right arrow
    }
}
rect( snake.X,snake.Y,20,20 );
```

I want the code to change the position of the block on the canvas, but all the Down arrow does when I push it is Write in the console, "Down Arrow." It will not display a rectangle at X: 200  Y: 200. Can somebody help? I am doing this for a snake game.

Comment: How do you know that line is being ignored?  What is `g`?

Comment: I know what line is being ignored because when I run it, it is not working. It is as if the program doesn't even know it is there. I picked the letter g because ctx didn't make any sense to me, and g is easier to type.

Comment: as the answer clearly shows, the line indeed was being executed, but the line by itself doesn't do anything that visibly changes anything on it's own.  Your program indeed creates a rect, but doesn't show it anywhere.  Your premise that your program "doesn't execute anything except console.log()" is flawed, but I'm glad someone was able to show you how to make it work all the same.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your program to draw the rectangle you have specified with the command `ctx.stroke();`. An example is shown in the snippet below, you need to click on the iframe and then press the down arrow for it to be registered.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

```js
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

if (e.keyCode == '38') {
}
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        console.log("Down Arrow");
        ctx.rect( 10,10,20,20); 
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right arrow
    }
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. IT WORKED!!